# Algorithms for calculating integrals

Tags: c++, integral

```
**
```

I wrote a program using the method of averages and we calculate it in two ways-by a given number of partitions of n and a given accuracy. Do I need to write a check so that the number of partitions is not zero or negative ( that is, write protection) or protection against non-numeric input ?
**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

double f(double);
double Metod(double (*f)(double), double, double, int);

void main()
{
    double a, b, eps, I1, I2, pogr;
    int n, n1, kod;
    cout << "If a=-2, b=3, Int=5,983" << endl;
    do {
        cout << "Input a:";
        cin >> a;
        cout << "Input b:";
        cin >> b;
        cout << "\n\t Input 1 - n, Else - eps : ";
        cin >> kod;
        if (kod == 1) {
            cout << "Input n: ";
            cin >> n;
            I1 = Metod(f, a, b, n);
        }
        else {
            cout << "Imput eps: ";
            cin >> eps;
            n1 = 2;
            I1 = Metod(f, a, b, n1);
            do {
                n1 *= 2;
                I2 = Metod(f, a, b, n1);
                pogr = fabs(I2 - I1);
                I1 = I2;
            } while (pogr > eps);
            cout << "\t n=" << n1 << endl;
        }
        cout << "\n\t Integral= " << I1 << endl;
        cout << "\n Repeat - 1, Else - Exit " << endl;
    } while (getch() == '1');
}

double f(double x)
{
    return 4 * x - 7 * sin(x);
}

double Metod(double (*f)(double x), double a, double b, int n)
{
    double s = 0, h, x;
    h = (b - a) / n;
    for (x = a + h / 2; x <= b; x += h) {
        s = s + f(x);
    }
    return h * s;
}
```

Comment: My personal opinion is always check everything entering the program.

Comment: Nowadays it is a must-to to code defensively. We need to create that habit from our very first program. Any input that can accept malformed data without proper validation will, most than likely, conduct to security vulnerabilites.